# How to replace values in multiple columns in a data.frame with values from a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, replace, gsub

I would like to replace the values in the last three columns in my data.frame with the three values in a vector.

Example of data.frame

```
df
A  B  C  D
5  3  8  9
```

Vector

```
1  2  3
```

what I would like the data.frame to look like.

```
df
A  B  C  D
5  1  2  3
```

Currently I am doing:

```
df$B <- Vector[1]
df$C <- Vector[2]
df$D <- Vector[3]
```

I would like to not replace the values one by one. I would like to do it all at once.

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can subset the last three columns of the dataset with `tail`, replicate the 'Vector' to make the lengths similar and assign the values to those columns

```
df[,tail(names(df),3)] <- Vector[col(df[,tail(names(df),3)])]
df
#  A B C D
#1 5 1 2 3
```

NOTE: I replicated the 'Vector' assuming that there will be more rows in the 'df' in the original dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df[-1] <- 1:3
```

giving:

```
> df
  A B C D
1 5 1 2 3
```

Alternately, we could do it non-destructively like this:

```
replace(df, -1, 1:3)
```

**Note:** The input `df` in reproducible form is:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 5, B =3, C = 8, D = 9)
```